# How can I achieve a similar plot output in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, matlab-figure

In Matlab, I had the following line to plot:

```
plot(x,y,'o',xx,YFIT,'-')
```

The output looked like this: 
[image]

What is the best way to go about the syntax for R plotting? First time working with plotting in R, so I'm asking for help. I can go into further explanation about my variables but since I'm just trying to translate the syntax, I wasn't sure if I'd need it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
matplot(xx,yy,type="l")
matlines (xx, YFIT, type = "l", lty = 1:ncol(yy), col = 1:ncol(yy))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I've given a tiny example of using ggplot to do what you want. Of course you don't want to prep your data as shown in the example. I suggest to use the 'melt' function in package 'reshape2' to translate your data from matrix format to long format expected by ggplot.

```
a.df <- data.frame(
    X=c(0,0.5,1.0),
    Y=c(0,0.25,1.0),
    ID = c("A","A","A")
)

b.df <- data.frame(
    X=c(0,0.5,1.0),
    Y=c(0,0.5,1.0),
    ID = c("B","B","B")
)

c.df <- data.frame(
    X=c(0,0.5,1.0),
    Y=c(0,0.75,1.0),
    ID = c("C","C","C")
)

display.df <- rbind(a.df, b.df, c.df)

ggplot(display.df, aes(X, Y, color=ID)) + geom_line()
```